# How to run getJSON function every minute inside window.setInterval?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have two working functions. How to run $.getJSON(..) every minute inside window.setInterval?

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
    functionCall(); // ??
}, 60000);
</script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       var query = "SELECT * FROM schedule;";
       $.getJSON(
                   'modules/mod_scheduler/updateList.php?query='+query,
                   function(data) 
                   {
                       createChartControl('schedule', data);
                   }   
       );
});
</script>
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

Answer (score 3):

```
<script>
window.setInterval(function(){
       var query = "SELECT * FROM schedule;";
       $.getJSON(
                   'modules/mod_scheduler/updateList.php?query='+query,
                   function(data) 
                   {
                       createChartControl('schedule', data);
                   }   
       );
}, 60000);
</script>
```

Though I feel compelled to add that passing SQL from your website frontend directly to your database is ***very very bad idea***.  A hacker get literally do anything they wanted with your database, from accessing private data to deleting your whole universe.

Comment: I want to echo the idea that passing SQL through an AJAX call is a VERY BAD idea.  Wouldn't take long for a hacker to get a list of tables and get all of the data from your database.  Or modify data, or drop the entire database.

Comment: Regarding the actual code, how do you prevent the server from caching the getJSON call?

Comment: How the server caches things should not be the concern of the client.